# How to deal with large 3D data arrays for better performance?

Tags: arrays, cuda, fortran

I am dealing with big data, stored in 3D arrays. Here is a kernel example of what I did (called in a for loop by the CPU) :

```
attributes(global) subroutine mykernel (A,B,C,p,nx,ny,nz)

real,dimension(:,:,:),device :: A,B
real,dimension(:),device :: C
real,device :: p
integer,device :: nx,ny,nz

xInd = blockDim.x * (blockIdx.x-1) + threadIdx.x;
yInd = blockDim.y * (blockIdx.y-1) + threadIdx.y;
zInd = blockDim.z * (blockIdx.z-1) + threadIdx.z;

if (xInd<=nx) then
 if (yInd<=ny) then
  if (zInd<=nz) then
   A(xInd,yInd,zInd)=(A(xInd,yInd+1,zInd)-A(xInd,yInd,zInd))*p-(B(xInd,yInd,zInd+1)-C(yInd)+B(xInd+1,yInd,zInd))*p+C(yInd+1)
  end if
 end if
end if

end subroutine mykernel
```

Everything seems fine when I'm launching the kernel, GPU results are the same as CPU results... But performances are not really great, in terms of time.

I think it is due to memory access here, but I'm not sure. I would have put my 3D arrays in the shared memory, but I'm dealing with nx*ny*nz > 1M data, so there isn't enough space in the shared memory.

So my following questions are about performances issues, with a large set of data :

- Should I flatten my 3D arrays to 1D arrays ? Will I get a boost ?
- Is it possible to read (memory access) large arrays of data without using global or shared memory ?
- What are the other possibilities of performances issues in this case ?

Comment: Assuming this function is called in a DO loop or the like, you would require in-lining to bring the function call overhead under control.  Even then, your conditional statements would appear to prevent important optimizations such as vectorization.  In the absence of optimizations which effectively linearize the array access, you might see a gain by 1D flattening.  I would think you wouldn't see the memory model performance until the other issues are resolved.

Comment: So I need to add an option to the compiler for in-lining my kernel ? What I understand about in-lining is replacing a function call to his own code. The if statements are expensive here ? I will try to flatten in 1D if so, thanks ! I'll be interested if there's something more than global or shared memory for optimizations, when dealing with big arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think I have figured out what are my issues here, in my case.

First, the execution configuration of my kernels. Working with 3D arrays seems not to be a good idea, because I use too much threads. For example, here I choose to work with blocks of 512 threads. So I call mykernel with 512*(348/8+1)*(145/8+1)*(113/8+1)= 6 590 628 Threads. 
If I flatten my 3D array to 1D, I only use 512*((348*145*113)/512+1)=5 702 492 Threads. **But why using more threads impacts my performances here ?**

Morover, in the CPU loop (where I call mykernel) : I was using too much transfers between the CPU and the GPU. So, to reduce the time of these transfers I used the pinned memory which is quite efficient. I strongly recommand this link for more explanations on [how to optimize data transfers](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-optimize-data-transfers-cuda-fortran/).

With all these things, my GPU code works x16 times faster than the CPU code, which is quite great ! The first version of my code was working "only" x7 times better.

Hope it could help.